# is there a generic, explicit primitive -> object cast in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, types, casting, prototype

I have the following puzzle (works in NodeJS):

```
console.log((42).toFixed);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(42));
```

While the first line does show `[Function: toFixed]`, the second fails with `TypeError: Object.getPrototypeOf called on non-object`. This, I believe, is the correct behavior as for the spec (but puzzling for anyone how believes that *everything is an object in JavaScript*).

Now I would like to write a method like `console.dir` that outputs all the properties of an object, including those coming from prototypes, and including those that are in fact accessible from primitive values.

Of course, the crux of the matter is that JavaScript tries to be smart and does a behind-the-scenes sleight-of-hand, casting the primitive value `42` to something akin to `new Number( 42 )`. The trick is done when you access a certain named property on the primitive value, but not when the value is an argument to `getPrototypeOf` (I believe it really should).

In order to reach my goal, I could go and determine the type of the primitive value in case `getPrototypeOf` should fail, and then pick from a hopefully limited number of possibilities (`Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, ...) the right one. this does not even sound difficult.

But it does feel a little ... wrong. What feels much better is a built-in / custom method `cast_as_object` that converts a primitive to an object no matter what its type is, preferably in some generic and future-proof way. Is that possible?

(n.b. It's trivial to go from type name to prototype when type names are unique and the set of primitives is small and closed—but I'm asking this question with the hope that answers will help people to better understand that theoretically simple yet practically intricate beast that is JavaScript's object model).

Comment: Are you asking a question or asking for a feature .. ?

Comment: assuming you find this elusive `cast-as_object`...what will be the benefits of using this new console method?

Comment: wouldn't the use of : var casted = new Object(studiedObject); be enough for your needs ? It must be exactly what js is doing when you are using the dot notation anyway.

Comment: i really wonder about those edits to my question. i mean, @Ken Kin even deleted spaces in my code where THEY think they're dispensible... changed all my lower-case `i` to that upper-case `I`... i know very well why i'm writing like this. i never asked for a spellcheck secretary on SO...

Comment: I'm sorry if you think it's a radical revision, I've flagged for the mod's attention.

Comment: it's less about it being rad or not, it's the fact it's been done at all... well i leave it at that. very diligent work. one oversight: `new Number( 42 )` still has spaces. i believe they help readability; others don't like them.

Answer (score 0):

@Ken Kin—asking for a feature *is* asking a question, no?—not sure what you're implying here.

@charlietfl—i believe i stated benefits in my text, to quote: "I would like to write a method like console.dir that outputs all the properties of an object". as it stands, `console.dir` will simply echo the stringification (what a word) of a primitive value (and, oddly, `new Object( 42 )` results in `{}`).

the solution turns out to be quite simple, as brought forth by @GameAlchemist: after doing

```
value = new Object( primitive_value )
```

you can apply `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and `Object.getPrototypeOf` to `value`, allowing to retrieve all properties on the object and the prototype chain.

Comment: What I've commented is because I don't quite understand the content in the post, and I tried to ask for a clarification that I can understand it better. The `value = new Object( primitive_value )` solution is in some way a bit different from `references as`, because it creates a new object.

Comment: i want to get a meaningful output from `dir( x )` even if `x` is a value that is unacceptable to `getPrototypeOf`. if you know that `x` is a primitive number and `Number` is its 'virtual' prototype then you can just report on `new Number()`—but that is not so nice because any new edition of JS could bring in a new primitive type. it's shorter, safer, more future-proof & probably faster to use `new Object( x )`. this is a throw-away value that is only there to get inspected; without it you get an error in your debugging code, or no truthful output, both of which are bad.

Comment: All the built-in types have the same syntax to cast such as `Number(value)` and `Object(value)`; as there is already the approach and you seem aware of it, that is why I don't understand your question.

Comment: as stated in my answer, i had not been aware of the simple solution. the credit goes to @GameAlchemist.